# Flutter: Content behind AppBar when using FlexibleSpacebar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement a collapsable AppBar, using a FlexibleSpaberBar and Tabs, the code "works" fine with the content of one of the tabs is a ListView, but, when the content is more static (inside a Column) and is smaller than the actual screen size, then when I scroll up in order to hide the FlexibleSpacebar, the content if the tab gets behind the app bar.

As you can see, the content of `Tab1Widget` is smaller than the screen size (although depending on the device actual screen size, it could be bigger than the screen size) and when I scroll up in order to hide the `FlexibleSpaceBar`, the content of `Tab1Widget` gets behind the AppBar

Attaching a working example to reproduce the problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return [
                SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                  handle:
                      NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                  sliver: SliverAppBar(
                    elevation: 0.0,
                    title: const Text("App Bar Demo"),
                    expandedHeight: 200.0,
                    floating: true,
                    pinned: true,
                    forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                    flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
                      background: Placeholder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                    pinned: true,
                    delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(TabBar(
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey[700],
                        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                        tabs: const [
                          Tab(
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text("Tab 1"),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text("Tab 2"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ])))
              ];
            },
            body: const TabBarView(
              children: [
                Tab1Widget(),
                Tab2Widet(),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

  final TabBar _tabBar;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      child: _tabBar,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

class Tab1Widget extends StatelessWidget {
  const Tab1Widget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverOverlapInjector(
              handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
            ),
            SliverSafeArea(
              sliver: SliverPadding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Column(
                      children: const [
                        Text(
                          "Content 1",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Content 2",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Content 3",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class Tab2Widet extends StatelessWidget {
  const Tab2Widet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

[image: Expanded State]
[image: Collapsed State]

Also, created a Dartpad [here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=960857dd4d2d601ae99d4e90b29494bd)

Comment: Use `SafeArea` around `home: const MyHomePage(),`. See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html